# Writing into buffers in PHP

Tags: php

I come from Node.JS and with it I simply do things like:

```
buf.writeUInt16LE(data, offset);
```

Now I need something similar in PHP. I currently have:

```
protected $tmpl = '06007007010001004B4';
$bytes = unpack('C*', $this->tmpl);
```

But the `pack` function doesn't seem to have an offset for an argument. Any alternatives?

Comment: Just use [`substr()`](http://php.net/substr) I suppose.

Comment: @Ja͢ck I can use substr to write into the bytes?

Comment: what is the output of first line `buf.writeUInt16LE(data, offset);`?

Comment: The line in nodejs. `buf.writeUInt16LE(data, offset);` what is the expected result for the statement?

Comment: It writes `data` into `buf` on the specified `offset`.